# Exclude some areas on filtering the DOM with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm filtering the entire DOM to replace some strings with other strings.

For this I wrote the following code:

```
$('body :not(script)').contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType === 3;
}).replaceWith(function() {
  return this.nodeValue.replace('T 0','T&nbsp;&nbsp;0');
});
```

How can I exclude some areas? For example I want the DIV with the class `.example` not to be considered.

I tried the following:

```
$('body :not(script):not(.example)').contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType === 3;
}).replaceWith(function() {
  return this.nodeValue.replace('T 0','T&nbsp;&nbsp;0');
});
```

Why does this not seem to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now, you're telling jQuery to exclude the node `.example`, which has children nodes, that WILL be included.

In your `:not()` selector add an `*` after the class.  This will tell jQuery to exclude all nodes underneath the parent node.

In CSS the `*` is a [universal selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors)

> The CSS universal selector (*) matches elements of any type.

Here's a working version:
(Please note that I changed the `&nbsp;` to `-` to visually show the change)

```js
$( "input:not(:checked) + span" ).css( "background-color", "yellow" );
$( "input").attr( "disabled", "disabled" );

$('body :not(script):not(div.example *)').contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType === 3;
}).replaceWith(function() {
  return this.nodeValue.replace('T 0','T--0');
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>not demo</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="example">
  <p>Remains the same:</p>
  <h1>T 0</h1>
</div>

<div>
  <p>Changes:</p>
  <h1>T 0</h1>
</div>
 
</body>
</html>
```